# ng-repeat is showing data that is not there

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using data load dynamically through a function and then populate using ng-repeat.

Below is the controller code.

```
$scope.loadproducts = function(item_id) {

        var pdata = $.param({
            item_id : item_id,
        });

        $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: baseurl + 'api/get_items_in_category_cart',
            data: pdata,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.items = response.data.products;
            $scope.description = response.data.description;
            console.log($scope.items);
             $timeout(apply_tooltip, 500);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {

        });
    };
```

View

```
<div class="container col-md-6" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">{{ item.title }}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img ng-src="{{ item.thumbnail }}"></a></div>
            <div class="col-md-9" style="">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 500;">{{ item.description }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 text-right" style=" text-align: left;">
                        <p>{{item.price | currency:"NZ $"}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8" style="  text-align: left;">

                        <input type="text" value="{{item.qty}}" style="width:50px; height: 28px; line-height: 28px;" readonly id="qty_{{item.id}}"/>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Upon initial page load the the code does what it is supposed to do.
There is a proceed button where the user gets taken to another page.
If the user goes back, the items are supposed to reload again.

The issue is during the reload the text box that is supposed to show the quantity for each item ->> value="{{item.qty}}" seems to show the same qty for all qty text boxes regardless of the original qty they had.

The console.log($scope.items) shows the proper value that it is supposed to have. It's just the display that is showing the wrong qty.

Any idea guys?

Comment: what does your apply_tooltip do?

Comment: Shows a tool tip on hover

Comment: can you try wrap             $scope.items = response.data.products;
            $scope.description = response.data.description; in to a $timeout(0) as well?

Comment: Sorry I'm lost. Can u suggest an example please

Comment: I doubt it may be because of same `id`, try adding `track by` in `ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id"`

Answer (score 0):

**If your data is loaded correctly**, you can go in two ways:

1 - Try to use a ng-model in your input

```
<input type="text" ng-model="item.qty" style="width:50px; height: 28px; line-height: 28px;" readonly id="qty_{{item.id}}"/>
```

You can either remove the 'readonly' property and add a ng-disabled="true".

2 - You can try to clear your list before you get the new values. So, before you load again your values from back-end you could just clear your data:

```
$scope.items = [];
```

And put the data again when the request is completed.

Note that this second solution it isn't conventional, and should be used in case that you can't find out another solution.